# AppEngine X-AppEngine-Inbound-AppId received in servlet but not in Endpoint

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets

I am using Google Appengine Java endpoints with internal microservices(Modules).

When I execute a call from the endpoints to a module Servlet I receive the  X-AppEngine-Inbound-AppId as per documentation(request.getHeader("X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid") and is all good.
When I try to call a module endpoint I don't receive it anymore!!

I am using the same code to execute all the HTTP requests.

```
  public GenericResponse makePOSTRequest(String urlString, Object requestObject, String jSessionId, boolean parseSessionId) {
    GenericResponse genericResponse;

    String rawPayload = mJsonParser.toJson(requestObject);
    URL url = new URL(urlString);

    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
    connection.setConnectTimeout(60000);
    connection.setReadTimeout(60000);

    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(rawPayload.getBytes("UTF-8").length));

    if (jSessionId != null) {
        connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" + jSessionId);
    }

    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
    writer.write(rawPayload);
    writer.close();

    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }
    br.close();

    if (!parseSessionId) {
        genericResponse = new GenericResponse(connection.getResponseCode(), sb.toString());
    } else {
        String responseSessionId = parseSessionId(connection);
        genericResponse = new GenericResponse(connection.getResponseCode(), sb.toString(), responseSessionId);
    }


    return genericResponse;
```